# cannot custom color span asp-validation-for .net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am using "span asp-validation-for=" to appear the error message when something wrong. But, I want to change the color, in spite I have class="text-danger" the color stay black. I have bootstrap and it works fine.
I took a screenshot (chrome page with inspector) [image: *screenshot here]. Thanks a lot everybody

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font- 
 awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="~/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- <script src="login.js" defer></script> -->
<title>Please Login - Mrx Systems</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
        <img src="~/img/LogoMRXSystemsLogin.svg" alt="Logo_Mrx_Systems" />
        <form asp-action="Login" id="form_login" data-ajax="true">
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <label for="input_text">Username</label>
                <div class="input_field">
                    <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control input" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <label for="input_password">Password</label>
                <div class="input_field">
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control input" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <label for="input_text">Database</label>
                <div class="input_field">
                    <input asp-for="db" class="form-control input"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="db" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <span class="error_msg">Incorrect username or password. Please try 
                   again</span>
                <input type="submit" id="login_btn" class="btn" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    color: #232323;      <<<<< i deleted this line
```

}

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.